# How do I get discord bot to send a message to channel after it disconnects?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

For my discord bot, I want it to send a message after it has left a voice channel to only the text channel that the command was used. I've tried doing this through an event, but that sent a message to every channel.

Here is my code:

```
class Commands(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot  


    
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):

        if not member.id == self.bot.user.id:                       
            return

        elif before.channel is None:                                
            voice = after.channel.guild.voice_client
            time = 0
            while True:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)                              
                time += 1
                if voice.is_playing() and not voice.is_paused():
                    time = 0
                if time == 10:
                    await voice.disconnect()
                if not voice.is_connected:                          
                    break
            
                    
    
    @commands.command(pass_context = True)
    async def play(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
            await channel.connect()
```

Is there a way to detect when the bot leaves within the play command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) event handler should handle any type of [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState) change, and `before` and `after` hold data about the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState) before and after the change. In particular, `after.channel` is `None` if `member` got disconnected from `before.channel`. You can simply add the line at the beginning of your function.

```py
VOICE_CHANNELS = {}

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):
    # Make sure the member is the bot
    if not member.id == self.bot.user.id:                       
        return

    # Bot got disconnected
    if after.channel is None:
        text_channel = VOICE_CHANNELS.pop(before.channel.id)
        if text_channel:
            await text_channel.send("Disconnected!")

    # Bot got connected
    elif before.channel is None:                                
        voice = after.channel.guild.voice_client
        time = 0
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(1)                              
            time += 1
            if voice.is_playing() and not voice.is_paused():
                time = 0
            if time == 10:
                await voice.disconnect()
            if not voice.is_connected:                          
                break

@commands.command(pass_context = True)
async def play(self, ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()
        VOICE_CHANNELS[channel.id] = ctx.channel
```

Comment: instead of sending the message to the text channel, the message was sent to the voice channel chat.

Comment: Ah I see what you want. I have updated the answer - a solution was to keep track of everything using a dictionary. Is this better?